# identifier starts immediately after numeric litera

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm showing a couple of videos on my website and generates the code after what YoutubeID the video has. Until now, it worked without problem but with the ID 6BD2qnBozvE, my script won't work.

**My code**

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {

    e3fqE01YYWs = document.getElementById('e3fqE01YYWs');
      setTimeout(function(){
        e3fqE01YYWs.setVolume(100);
        e3fqE01YYWs.playVideo();
      }, 750);

    6BD2qnBozvE = document.getElementById('6BD2qnBozvE');
      setTimeout(function(){
        6BD2qnBozvE.setVolume(53);
        6BD2qnBozvE.playVideo();
      }, 750);
        }
```

**Error message in Firebug**

> identifier starts immediately after numeric literal [Break On This
>   Error]
>
> 6BD2qnBozvE = document.getElementById('6BD2qnBozvE');

Why does this occur and how can I fix it?

Edit: Jeremy Banks explains why but I still don't know how to fix my problem.

This is how I generate my Javascript code:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
<?php
foreach($projectMusicUn as $music => $volume){
?> 
<?php echo $music; ?> = document.getElementById('<?php echo $music; ?>');
setTimeout(function(){
    <?php echo $music; ?>.setVolume(<?php echo $volume; ?>);
<?php echo $music; ?>.playVideo();
  }, 750);
<?php
} //End of foreach($projectMusic as $music)
?>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign to a variable named `6BD2qnBozvE`. This isn't allowed; variable names (identifiers) in JavaScript must start with a letter, underscore or `$`.

Just rename it something like `video_6BD2qnBozvE`. While you're at it, you should probably add the `var` keyword before the definition so you don't create a global variable.

```
    var video_6BD2qnBozvE = document.getElementById('6BD2qnBozvE');
```

---

Add a prefix like `video_` each time it's used as a variable in your generating source code:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    <?php
    foreach($projectMusicUn as $music => $volume){
        ?> 
        var video_<?php echo $music; ?> = document.getElementById('<?php echo $music; ?>');
        setTimeout(function(){
            video_<?php echo $music; ?>.setVolume(<?php echo $volume; ?>);
            video_<?php echo $music; ?>.playVideo();
        }, 750);
        <?php
    } //End of foreach($projectMusic as $music)
    ?>
}
```

Comment: That explains why... Still don't know how to fix it and have updated my question with the code on how I generate the Javascript.